# using TRIM() in PIG for individual records

Tags: apache-pig

I am loading a file into PIG. After splitting the records using `STRSPLIT(doc,',')` I would like to clean up the data using `TRIM()` to get rid of extra white spaces. I cannot seem to figure out how to use `TRIM()` on every word in a record. Example:

```
((car , truck, jeep , honk)).
```

The schema for this is:  `tokens:(t:(w:chararray))`
I have tried

```
clean_docs = FOREACH tokenized_docs GENERATE TRIM(tokens.$0.w) AS tokens:(t:(w:chararray));
```

And many other variations, and cannot seem to make it work. 
Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right now I don't think there is a built-in solution for doing this and you would need to either flatten everything or do an Eval UDF that takes the list of strings and trim each element (cleaner solution).

However, doing a TRIM on the whole string then using a regular expression that cuts the spaces too might work?
e.g.

> STRSPLIT(doc,' *, *')